# Getting USB Serial Port Parameters

Tags: java, usb

I am trying to read the output stream from a GPS chip, attached to my computer via a USB cable, using the RXTX API.

My Java reads

`sp.setSerialPortParams(4800, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);`

My app currently outputs `Scanning port /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port`

So I believe my Bluetooth port is number 4800?

Running `ls /dev/tty.*`gives `/dev/tty.usbserial` only when the GPS is plugged in, so this is my device. I also see the Bluetooth device.

So I think I need to change the number in my Java code - how do I get the usbserial device number?

Comment: 4800 is the baudrate - your gps-usb-connection seems to have internally an usb<-->serial adapter. I cant tell you where the serial port would be mapped, when i used an usb<-->serial adapter it was port COM4 (on an windows machine)....  but it might me linked to somewhere else on your computer...

Comment: when your serial port is really /dev/tty.usbserial you can create an serial port with rxtx on that port; once you created that serial port you can simply read from that port like you would read from an ... ...socket ...or any other stream

Comment: 4800 is the baudrate - thanks Martin, another piece of the puzzle fits into place.

Comment: Hello Ben, i used to work with RXTX, if i can assiste in any way let me know! - btw RXTX rocks!!!!

Comment: Hi Martin, _only if_ you have a spare moment, I have a follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466396/java-marine-api-looking-for-nmea-data. Perhaps your expertise is relevant, thank you for your assistance so far.